# What are the differences between runit and supervisord?

Tags: rhel, supervisord, django

I'm looking into changing our Django deployments and was reading [the deploy page](http://gunicorn.org/deploy.html) for [gunicorn](/questions/tagged/gunicorn) and it talks about both [supervisord](/questions/tagged/supervisord) which I was aware of and planning on using and [runit](/questions/tagged/runit) that I don't recall hearing about before. Why would I pick one over the other?

We are running red hat.

Answer (score 2):

Supervisord is [not designed or intended to run as the init process](http://supervisord.org/), PID 1, [while runit is](http://smarden.org/runit/).  This means that in addition to service management, runit also has code for reaping the orphaned children of other processes, [handling startup and shutdown](http://smarden.org/runit/runit.8.html), [runlevels](http://smarden.org/runit/runlevels.html), and [dependencies between services](http://smarden.org/runit/dependencies.html), while supervisord [does not do these things](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/122), and is designed to operate with any init system.  While [it is possible to use runit without replacing your existing init system](http://smarden.org/runit/useinit.html), that isn't really what it's designed for.  I would expect a runit installation to be a deeper and more error-prone operation than a supervisord setup (which I have done, and which is pretty painless), but if you need the ability to delay the launch of processes until other processes have come up, then supervisord will not be adequate.